# How to return dataframe after df.apply()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have a pandas data frame `df`

```
[In] df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
```

Due to the empty column, I drop the last two columns of `df`

```
[In] csv_df.drop(csv_df.columns[-2:], axis = 1, inplace=True)
[In] print(type(csv_df[csv_df.columns[2:]]))
```

The return data structure is

```
[Out] <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

However, when I manipulate the content of all the x by `df.apply()`, the return type changed to pandas series.

```
# replace comma
[In] csv_df = csv_df[csv_df.columns[2:]].apply(lambda x: str(x).replace(',','.'))
[In] print(type(csv_df))
[Out] <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

I have checked the pandas official website of [`apply()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html), it said that it can return either series or dataframe.

> Returns:   applied : Series or DataFrame

#### My question is

How can I keep the data structure to be pandas dataframe after `df.apply()`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's 'return', not 'reuturn'... tried to edit, but you changed it back :/

Comment: @l'L'l thanks! My apology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use operation working with `DataFrame` here - [`DataFrame.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) for convert to `string`s and [`DataFrame.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html):

```
csv_df = csv_df[csv_df.columns[2:]].astype(str).replace(',','.')
```

If need solution with apply, especially if working by some function working in Series only:

```
csv_df = csv_df[csv_df.columns[2:]].apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.replace(',','.'))
```

Function `str.lower` working only in `Series`:

```
csv_df = csv_df[csv_df.columns[2:]].apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.lower().str.replace(',','.'))
```

Comment: `csv_df = csv_df[csv_df.columns[2:]].apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.replace(',','.'))` works like a charm. However on my system configuration, `csv_df = csv_df[csv_df.columns[2:]].astype(str).replace(',','.')` doesn't work. I'm still working on the reason. I'm appreciated!

Comment: @WYHsu - because use `.repalce` function, not `str.replace`. You need `.replace(',','.', regex=True)` for substrings replacement

Answer (score 1):

If this can help, just Pass result_type=’expand’

```
df.apply(lambda x: [4, 7], axis=1, result_type='expand')
```

Comment: Hi, could you please elaborate a little more why you choose `result_type=’expand’`? btw thanks for the help!

Comment: because this is mentioned in the official website, 
 apply() :- "Passing result_type=’expand’ will expand list-like results to columns of a Dataframe"

Comment: I saw it, thanks! But the manual said that: list-like results will be returned as a Series of those. However if the apply function returns a Series these are expanded to columns. Maybe I should try ‘broadcast’?